# Chrome extension: have an extension listen for an event when type in address bar?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I want to listen when user type in address bar? Did chrome allow to do this?

It like : `onInputChanged.addListener(function(text){console.log(text)});`

Comment: The only thing (remotely) similar would be: [chrome.omnibox](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/omnibox), but only works for previously specified keyword

Answer (score 4):

There's no such event.

The alternative is [chrome.omnibox API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/reference/omnibox) which requires users to type your specified keyword first, and then your extension receives the typed text in various event listeners of this API.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Actually I want to make a extension send request everytime user type in address bar and receive a response. Those response will be filled into address bar. I can do that with `chrome.omnibox API ` but only works for previously specified keyword. It's really annoying users because they don't want to type any pecified keyword before they type in address bar.

Comment: The Evernote web clipper has a feature that whenver I enter a search term in the address bar will retrieve notes in my account that match the term. Can you give a suggestion on how to do that? I'm thinking of having my extension detect the url, and make a GET request to Evernote API if it is google.com/search?q, but the results returned by Evernote seems faster than that.

Comment: @catwhocodes you should inspect the code of their extension and/or ask a new question with the results of your investigation.

Comment: Unfortunately, the Evernote web clipper is close-sourced. Thanks for replying.

Comment: @catwhocodes you can inspect and debug any extension inside the browser. It might be inconvenient if it's minified or obfuscated though.

Comment: I'm unable to capture any address bar suggestion requests with either webNavigation API or webRequest API. I suppose this no longer works.

Comment: It was intentionally disabled several years ago, indeed.